# Is there a plan to add people packge to ROS Noetic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is people package available for ROS Melodic. (https://wiki.ros.org/people)
Is there any plan to add this package to ROS Noetic in the near future?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359374/is-there-a-plan-to-add-people-packge-to-ros-noetic?/) by [PKGosal](https://answers.ros.org/users/56803/pkgosal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an open issue to release to Noetic: https://github.com/wg-perception/people/issues/83 . It looks like the [maintainer has started work, and is now welcoming contributions](https://github.com/wg-perception/people/issues/83#issuecomment-660243433) to help finish it.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKGosal](https://answers.ros.org/users/56803/pkgosal/) on 2020-08-12**:
Thank you!